# How to duplicate / clone sql records with a diffrent id in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, clone, record

I have a database structure as follows:

```
P_Id    content     FirstName   
1       Hansen      Timoteivn 10    
1       Svendson    Tove    
1       Pettersen   Kari
```

I would like to be able to duplicate every entry with P_Id as 1 replacing P_id with 2. At the end of the statement I would like to have:

```
P_Id    content     FirstName   
1       Hansen      Timoteivn 10    
1       Svendson    Tove    
1       Pettersen   Kari 
2       Hansen      Timoteivn 10    
2       Svendson    Tove    
2       Pettersen   Kari
```

Any help would be great!

I have an update to my question. What if the table contained multiple entries and I wanted to target specific rows? For instance:

```
P_Id    content      FirstName   
1       Hansen1      Timoteivn 101    
1       Svendson1    Tove1    
1       Pettersen1   Kari1
2       Hansen2      Timoteivn 102    
2       Svendson2    Tove2    
2       Pettersen2   Kari2
3       Hansen3      Timoteivn 103    
3       Svendson3    Tove3    
3       Pettersen3   Kari3
```

How would I go about duplicating every P_ID with the value of 2 to P_ID with 4? Resulting in:

```
P_Id    content     FirstName   
1       Hansen1      Timoteivn 101    
1       Svendson1    Tove1    
1       Pettersen1   Kari1
2       Hansen2      Timoteivn 102    
2       Svendson2    Tove2    
2       Pettersen2   Kari2
3       Hansen3      Timoteivn 103    
3       Svendson3    Tove3    
3       Pettersen3   Kari3
4       Hansen2      Timoteivn 102    
4       Svendson2    Tove2    
4       Pettersen2   Kari2
```

Thanks guys, this is the final part of the site I am building!

Answer (score 3):

To duplicate all records with a P_Id of 'x' to a P_Id of 'y' (where x and y are numbers) the SQL would be

```
INSERT INTO yourtable 
    SELECT y AS 'P_Id', content, FirstName 
    FROM yourtable 
    WHERE P_Id = x
```

remember to replace 'yourtable' with the name of your table!

Comment: `INSERT INTO yourtable SELECT (SELECT MAX(P_Id)+1 FROM yourtable) AS 'P_Id', content, FirstName FROM yourtable`

Comment: That is great but what if the table contained multiple entries and I wanted to target specific rows? For instance:

    P_Id    content     FirstName   
    1       Hansen      Timoteivn 10    
    1       Svendson    Tove    
    1       Pettersen   Kari
    2       Hansen      Timoteivn 10    
    2       Svendson    Tove    
    2       Pettersen   Kari

Comment: That is great but what if the table contained multiple entries and I wanted to target specific rows? For instance:

    P_Id    content     FirstName   
    1       Hansen1      Timoteivn 101    
    1       Svendson1    Tove1    
    1       Pettersen1   Kari1
    2       Hansen2      Timoteivn 102    
    2       Svendson2    Tove2    
    2       Pettersen2   Kari2
    3       Hansen3      Timoteivn 103    
    3       Svendson3    Tove3    
    3       Pettersen3   Kari3

How would I go about duplicating every P_ID with the value of 2 to P_ID with 4? Resulting in: